# Better way to create instance and run method in .NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have converted my .NET 4.5 to .NET 5, and everything seems to be about DI, which is great.

In order to load all my AutoMapper configuration files, i thought i would create an interface against them all, and then i need to execute the method, which i did like this.

```
// interface
public interface IAutoMapperMapping
{
    void Apply();
}

// class that implements interface
public class PageMapping : IAutoMapperMapping
{
    public void Apply()
    {
        // mappaing config here
    }
}

// load all classes
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    // Load all mappings files and apply
    var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var types = assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(e => typeof(IAutoMapperMapping).IsAssignableFrom(e) && !e.IsInterface)
        .ToList();

    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        var instance = (IAutoMapperMapping)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        instance.Apply();
    }
}
```

Is this the best way to do this in .NET 5, or in .NET in general, or have i done something bad that i should avoid?

Comment: What are you concerns? Is there a specific part you are concerned about?

Comment: I didnt know if there was a feature i should really be using, or whether since .NET is heavy on DI, should i be doing this another "DI" way, rather then using CreateInstance

Comment: Nope. There is no batch-registration facility in the new DI system, so you'll have to hand-code this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not actually registering any types to the ASP.NET 5 services DI container. What you are doing though is called Assembly Scanning and is a common feature of a lot of Dependency Injection containers.

The default container in ASP.NET 5 is very basic and does not include the ability to register types in the assembly using assembly scanning. If you wanted to, you could register all the types with the ASP.NET 5 services container and then rely on the container to resolve the `IAutomapperMapping` type, rather than using `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Alternatively, you can use a container like [Autofac](http://autofac.org/) (There are many other good ones too but I like this one because it has a large community behind it and even Microsoft used it for Azure Mobile Services). You can read about Autofac [Assembly Scanning](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html) and about their support for ASP.NET 5 [here](http://druss.co/2015/05/vnext-asp-net-5-dependency-injection/). However, you should note that this is all beta quality code.